# Issues with pyinstaller

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I have created a working GUI program (using tkinter), but when I try to compile it using pyinstaller (py2exe only works for python 2.6 and I used 2.7 for the program), it doesn't work. I have 2 files: program.py, and data.xml. The program uses the xml document to retrieve information and display it to the window. I have looked all over, but no one seems to have had a similar problem, and the pyinstaller documentation is useless. the command I used was

```
python pyinstaller.py -w -mdata.xml -nProgram program.py
```

It appears to make the spec file fine, but generates an error with a large traceback upon build:

```
pyinstaller.utils.winmanifest.invalidManifestError: Invalid root element <items> - has to be one of <assembly>, <assemblyBinding>, <configuration>, <dependentAssembly>
```

and quits the build process. This is the first time I have tried to build an executable for a project, so I'm kind of shooting in the dark here. Did I forget to do something, or did I just find a bug in pyinstaller's program?

Comment: I took a look into the issue a bit more, and have figured out that it probably doesn't like the xml. the root tag in my xml document is <items> so do I have to add anything before that, or make it different? Is there any sort of prefix that I need to add to my xml document to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't answer my own question, but I have solved the issue and I think others should know about this. When creating your program and using an xml with it, you must have the root tag (the first one) as `<assembly>`. Not sure why, but it works when I do that. also, don't forget to use the `--hidden-import=Module` command if you imported anything into your program.

Comment: Do you think it is worth opening an issue? Then I would do so. If you think it is no more relevant or it has already been reported, then please tell us. But I think it makes sense :-)

Comment: I haven't used pyinstaller in years. I'm not sure if this issue is even still relevant. Someone else will have to investigate and see if this is an issue that should be addressed.

Comment: I have searched a little and found https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3704 .
This is not completely the same but related enough. Because the report was about PyInstaller 3.3.1 and not 3.4, the issue was closed! Makes me sad to see a nice project too little supported.